# AMP-sidebar; opens on button click but directly closes again; only occurs from amp-cache

Tags: amp-html

I have a website that is mostly AMP compatible and I dont have a non-amp version.
I use a amp-sidebar for the menu on small screens. Everything works fine when resizing on desktop and validates fine in the amp validator.
When I enter the url https://hpphysio.com on my android smartphone there also is no problem.
But when I google hp physio and open the amp-cached version from the google results, the page is broken. The sidebar occurs but immediately closes again when pressing the menu button. This happens in 9 of 10 tries. Sometimes the menu stays open.
The site is unusable when loaded from the amp-cache.
What might be the problem?

Comment: You can also check your code, I've checked your home page and saw 15 errors using the [amp validator](https://validator.ampproject.org/). Try fixing it, I also didn't experience your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the homepage on google cache and didn't find any issue

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fhpphysio.com&oq=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fhpphysio.com&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.2541j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8